# htaccess gives 404 i qualified the page is there

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site created specific for mobiles. I added the code below into my htaccess for a redirect but it does not seem to work.

Can anyone enlighten me please

```
#custom redirects

RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /cartypes.php?cartype=12 http://m.cartypecompany.com/redcars.php
```

#end custom redirects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Redirect` directive is not used with `mod_rewrite`'s `RewriteEngine On` and you need a `RewriteCond` to match query string. Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =m.cartypecompany.com
RewriteRule ^redcars\.php$ /cartypes.php?cartype=12 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: I would be most grateful for the help. Can you confirm...... that the http://www.cartypecompany.com/cartypes.php?cartype=12 is been renamed as /redcars.php as I do not have a page called red cars at all. I wanted the specific /cartypes.php?cartype=12 to be named red cars....... I say this due to me getting 404s, and you only get a 404 if a page is not present. the snippet you have given me.... does it rewrite the page name from /cartypes.php?cartype=12 to redcars.php ??????

Comment: Thank you, does this mean I have to create a page call redcars.php or does it just rename /cartypes.php?cartype=12 as redcars.php.........I had hoped it would rename the  /cartypes.php?cartype=12 thus a punter on visiting the page redcar.php would see it with related content.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cartype=12$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?cartypes\.php$ http://m.cartypecompany.com/redcars.php? [L,NC,R=301]

Does the above code rewrite /cartypes.php?cartype=12 to /redcars.php

If so why would I get a 404?

You have mentioned "Yes above rule redirects /cartypes.php?cartype=12 to /redcars.php"
I do not have a page called redcars.php I wanted the page been filtered /cartypes.php?cartype=12 to be renamed /redcars.php

Comment: Thank you very much....... it works... and I am very grateful. the stress of trying to get this to work lol. your a gentleman  good luck.

Comment: You're most welcome, rule was actually doing reverse earlier.